Moving a part of the forest
I have the following forest (thanks to the help on the website) but I need to move the nodes located on the left ((5,5,5) and (1,1,1)) closer to the rest of the tree.
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{every label/.style = {font=\footnotesize,  text=red,
                               inner sep=1pt }}

\begin{document}    

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {
        draw, 
        s sep=5mm, 
        l sep=5mm,
        edge={thick,-Latex},
                }
[{(5,5,6)}, label=right:{(1,2)},s sep=1cm
    [{(5,5,5)},no edge,name=k,
        [{(1,1,1)} ]]
    [{(4,4,4)}, 
        [{(2,3,3)}, name=c
            [{(1,1,2)}, label=left:{(1,0)}, name = d    
                [{(0,0,0)}, label=below:{(0,1)}]
            ]
    ]        
]
    [{(3,4,5)}, label=right:{(0,1)}, name=f
        [{(2,2,4)}, label=below:{(2,2)}, name = g]
    [{(1,3,4)}, label=right:{(1,0)}
            [{(0,2,2)}, label=below:{(0,1)}, name = h]
            [{(0,1,3)}, label=below:{(0,1)}, name = j]
            ]        
        ]    
    ]
]
\draw[thick, -Latex] (f) -- (c);
\draw[thick, -Latex] (c) -- (h);
\draw[thick, -Latex] (g) -- (d);
\draw[thick, -Latex] (g) -- (j);
\draw[thick, -latex] (k) -- (c);
\end{forest}
\end{document}

Is it possible to adjust that?
The reason is that I want the picture to take less space in width without changing the size of nodes.

You can play with the s sep value in the (5,5,6) node, (e.g. try .75cm) but because of your labels you're quite restricted in how much you can move the leftmost nodes to the right.

Since this structure is not a tree, you may be better off using the graph drawing library or even just a matrix of nodes. It's a bit of a tradeoff how much you gain from forest syntax once the tree properties disappear.

Since you don't have labels in between any siblings, you could just remove s sep=1cm. If necessary, you could also reduce the 5mm spacing for the tree as a whole.

\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{every label/.style = {font=\footnotesize,  text=red,
inner sep=1pt }}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree = {
draw,
s sep'=5mm,
l sep'=5mm,
edge={thick,-Latex},
}
[{(5,5,6)}, label=right:{(1,2)},%s sep=1cm
[{(5,5,5)},no edge,name=k,
[{(1,1,1)} ]]
[{(4,4,4)},
[{(2,3,3)}, name=c
[{(1,1,2)}, label=left:{(1,0)}, name = d
[{(0,0,0)}, label=below:{(0,1)}]
]
]
]
[{(3,4,5)}, label=right:{(0,1)}, name=f
[{(2,2,4)}, label=below:{(2,2)}, name = g]
[{(1,3,4)}, label=right:{(1,0)}
[{(0,2,2)}, label=below:{(0,1)}, name = h]
[{(0,1,3)}, label=below:{(0,1)}, name = j]
]
]
]
]
\draw[thick, -Latex] (f) -- (c);
\draw[thick, -Latex] (c) -- (h);
\draw[thick, -Latex] (g) -- (d);
\draw[thick, -Latex] (g) -- (j);
\draw[thick, -latex] (k) -- (c);
\end{forest}
\end{document}

You could also remove s sep=5mm and add fit=tight instead (which is anyway default, if I remember correctly), but things start to look a bit crowded:

